# Some difficultes with akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following code:

```
class App1 extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[Actor1])
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)       //1

  val future = actor1 ? "start"
  val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
  if (result == "string1") println("yes123)
  else println("no456")
}



class Actor1 extends Actor {

  actor2 = context.actorOf(Props[Actor2])

  def receive = {
    case "start" => {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)      // 2
      val future = actor2 ? "command1"                // 3
      val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
      sender ! result                                 // 4
    }
  }
}

class Actor2 extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "command1" => {
      // .... some calculations
      sender ! "result123"                           //5
    }
  }
}
```

This is not an exact code I have, it's just a simple version of it. The questions are the following:

1. Does the first timeout depend on the second one? if it does, must
   the first one be less, equal or more than the second one? `//1 and
   //2`
2. Should `Actor1` wait for the result from `Actor2`, should it use
   exactly future? Could it use `!` instead of `?` ? `// 3 and //4`
3. I just to make sure everything is ok. Do `//4` and `//5` return the value to the sender as they suppose to (using `!`)?

Please note that I can't test it by myself because this is much simple version of what I actually have, and I didn't find the answers to these particular question in the documentation.

Comment: As a note, you can change this `val future = actor1 ? "start"` to this `val future = (actor1 ? "start").mapTo[String]` and then drop the `.asInstanceOf[String]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The two timeouts are independent as far as akka is concerned. 
   However, from the comments below it seems that your concern is whether the longer timeout in //2 will cause //1 to timeout if actor2 takes longer than  5 seconds to reply,then yes this will indeed happen.
2. It depends on the semantics you are trying to implement. If you want actor 2 to block before you return you should use await. However the right solution here seems to return a future using pipeTo without blocking. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html
3. Yes that does what you intend.

Comment: As an alternative, if you are not doing anything with the result from `Actor2` in `Actor1`, you can forward the message instead of doing `?` or `!` and then just let `Actor2` respond directly to the original sender.  That would look like this: `actor2 forward "command1"`

Comment: However with `forward` you should keep in mind, the `sender` ref to the original sender will be returned instead of the mediator.

Comment: 1) `//1` -- this waits for 5 seconds, while `//2` waits for 10 seconds, right? Thus, if `//2` takes 10 seconds to receive the result from `future`, will it cause the exception in `//1` because `//1` is allowed to wait **only for 5 seconds** (while `//2` already has taken **10 seconds** to complete the request)?

Comment: @HarshalPandya, this not "yes" "no" question.

Comment: @MariusKavansky 1) //1 -- this waits for 5 seconds, while //2 waits for 10 seconds, right? **YES**  Thus, if //2 takes 10 seconds to receive the result from future, will it cause the exception in //1 because //1 is allowed to wait only for 5 seconds (while //2 already has taken 10 seconds to complete the request)? **Yes again**

Comment: If so then your first answer is wrong: the timeouts are not independent.

Comment: The timeouts are indeed independent, but some combinations make more sense than others. Actor1 might have other clients which wait longer. Another recommendation would be to replace the Await.result() with pipeTo.

Comment: what's the advantage Await.result() against pipeTo?